# How do I add a dropdown menu to a form?

Tags: customization, forms

I am trying to create a dropdown list that will insert numbers based on numbers already used for that group of numbers. Example: dropdown will include numbers such as (100, 200, 300, etc) and I want to append a group of numbers to them like this (100-0001). The appended numbers need to be sequential starting at 0001 but they need to be sequential according to which prefix is used. Also, I need to insert this dropdown on a form in Wordpress.

Comment: How is your form implemented? There's no code to work with in your question, please edit the question to include more information about what you have so far and what the form is intended for

Comment: Good point. Thank you for the feedback. I will modify this question.